# Finding the intersection of elements in two sets

Tags: java, set

Is there another better way to implement those two methods in **1** and **2**?

> 1. Implement the method `contains`.
>      `contains` returns true if the given element
>      is a member of the set, and false otherwise.
> 2. Implement the method `intersection`.
>      `intersection` returns a set which contains the elements
>      in the set that are also members of the given set
>
> **output**:
>
> ```
> {9, 1, 4, 3, 7, 5}
>
> {4, 2, 8, 5, 7}
>
> {4, 7, 5}
> ```

---

```
public class IntSet {

private int[] elements = null;

public IntSet(int[] elements) {
    this.elements = new int[elements.length];
    for (int pos = 0; pos < elements.length; pos++) {
        this.elements[pos] = elements[pos];
    }
}


// toString returns a string representation of the set
public String toString() {
    String s = "{";
    if (elements.length == 0)
        s = s + "}";
    else {
        for (int pos = 0; pos < elements.length - 1; pos++)
            s = s + elements[pos] + ", ";
        s = s + elements[elements.length - 1] + "}";
    }

    return s;
}

// contains returns true if the given element
// is a member of the set, and false otherwise.
public boolean contains(int element) {

    for (int i = 0; i < this.elements.length; i++) {
        if (this.elements[i] == element)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}


// intersection returns a set which contains the elements
// in the set that are also members of the given set
public IntSet intersection(IntSet set) {
    // use the method contains
    int members = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (set.contains(elements[i]))
            members++;
    }

    int[] newMembers = new int[members];
    int position = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (set.contains(elements[i]))
            newMembers[position++] = this.elements[i];

    }
    return new IntSet(newMembers);
}

//Some instances of the class IntSet are created and used like this:
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] numbers1 = {9, 1, 4, 3, 7, 5};
    IntSet set1 = new IntSet(numbers1);
    int[] numbers2 = {4, 2, 8, 5, 7};
    IntSet set2 = new IntSet(numbers2);
    System.out.println(set1);
    System.out.println(set2);

    IntSet set = set1.intersection(set2);
    System.out.println(set);
    //When this code fragment is executed, the following printout is produced:
    //{9, 1, 4, 3, 7, 5}
    //{4, 2, 8, 5, 7}
    //{4, 7, 5}
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not using [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) in 1st place?

Comment: In the task only two methods was asked to implement the other part of the code was giving within the task. So I'm open to learn if `HashSet<Integer>` Please share your knowledge I like to learn it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>     int[] numbers1 = {9, 1, 4, 3, 7, 5};
>     IntSet set1 = new IntSet(numbers1);
>     int[] numbers2 = {4, 2, 8, 5, 7};
>     IntSet set2 = new IntSet(numbers2);
>     System.out.println(set1);
>     System.out.println(set2);
>
>     IntSet set = set1.intersection(set2);
>     System.out.println(set);
>     //When this code fragment is executed, the following printout is produced:
>     //{9, 1, 4, 3, 7, 5}
>     //{4, 2, 8, 5, 7}
>     //{4, 7, 5}
>   }
> ```

Consider instead

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] numbers1 = {9, 1, 4, 3, 7, 5};
    Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(numbers1));
    Integer[] numbers2 = {4, 2, 8, 5, 7};
    Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(numbers2));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers1));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers2));

    Set<Integer> set = intersection(set1, set2);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(set.toArray()));
    //When this code fragment is executed, the following printout is produced:
    //{9, 1, 4, 3, 7, 5}
    //{4, 2, 8, 5, 7}
    //{4, 7, 5}
  }
```

This handles `contains` for you, as `Set` has a `contains` method.

Because this is a built-in data type,  you don't have to reinvent it.  And `HashSet` has constant time `contains`, `add`, and `remove`.

Then you just need to implement `intersection`.

```
public static Set<Integer> intersection(Set<Integer> a, Set<Integer> b) {
    // unnecessary; just an optimization to iterate over the smaller set
    if (a.size() > b.size()) {
        return intersection(b, a);
    }

    Set<Integer> results = new HashSet<>();

    for (Integer element : a) {
        if (b.contains(element)) {
            results.add(element);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

This will operate in linear time based on the size of the smaller set.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there another better way to implement those two methods in 1 and 2?

Of course there is.

My advice is to think about the problem as though you were solving the problem *without* a computer.

Here, I'm going to give you a list of a thousand unsorted integers between 0 and 999999.

Now I'm going to ask you *one thousand times* whether a particular number I've chosen *at random* is on the list.

Would you really try to answer every question by reading down the list from top to bottom *every time*?

Give some thought as to how you might solve that problem before you read on.

.

.

.

.

.

No, really, think about it.

.

.

.

You probably thought something like

- the first time I go down the list, I could make ten smaller lists:  numbers I've seen from 0-99999, numbers I've seen from 100000-199999, from 200000-299999, and so on.  That will take a thousand steps to make ten buckets of roughly 100 items each.
- Then the second time I'm asked the question, I can first figure out what *bucket* the number *might* be in. Then I can search that bucket, and I know I will only have around 100 things to check instead of 1000.
- And hey, while I'm doing that, I might as well divide *that* bucket up into ten buckets of roughly ten items each!

Every time you do a search that makes ten more buckets, you make *subsequent* searches that hit that bucket ten times faster.

All right, that should get you started; **can you implement something like this bucketing algorithm in code?**

Now, think the same way about intersection. **Can you use the same bucketing trick to make intersection vastly faster?** Or something similar?  Again, think about how you would solve the problem if I asked you to do it by hand.